# Работа с Euler Angles

Tags: c#, unity3d

Такой вопрос. Ограничиваю rotation объекта в игре, по оси y - все получилось, а по оси x - нет. Мне нужно ограничить от -40 до 40, но euler angles не принимает отрицательных значений. Код для ограничения по y -

```
if (_carTransform.eulerAngles.y < 160f)
    {
        _carTransform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, 160f, 0f);
    }
    else if (_carTransform.eulerAngles.y > 200f)
    {
        _carTransform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, 200f, 0f);
    }
    else
    {
        _carTransform.Rotate(_mouseDistance.y * _lookRateSpeed * Time.deltaTime, _mouseDistance.x * _lookRateSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, Space.Self);
    }
```

Может подскажет кто альтернативу или возможное решение с euler? Застопорился - ужас

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, надо поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 3):

```
[SerializeField] private Vector2 _LimitX = new Vector2(-60, 60);
private Transform _transform;

private void Awake () {
    _transform = transform;
}

private void Update () {
    Vector3 Angle = _transform.eulerAngles;
    while (Angle.x > 180f)
        Angle.x -= 360f;
    while (Angle.x < -180f)
        Angle.x += 360f;
    Angle.x = Mathf.Clamp(Angle.x, _LimitX.x, _LimitX.y);
    _transform.eulerAngles = Angle;
}
```

Comment: Ага, это аналог, но он не работает в моем случае. Объект при пересечении\достижении отметки в 0 градусов - возвращается к LimitX.y и он просто как лягушка - скачет, при попытке наклонить его.

Comment: Ну да, это потому, что угол может стать не -10, а 350. Нужно предварительно пошаманить с значением и привести к формату.

Comment: Хех, ну вот, я с этим вопросом здесь изначально =)

Comment: Да, спасибо. Исправленный вариант мне подходит